# Akka: finding the actor ref using a path

Tags: java, akka

I am new to Akka and I am trying to start an Actor and send messages to that actor from various other actors. The receiver is called Hero and the senders are Messengers

Here is my Hero class

```
import akka.actor.UntypedActor;

public class Hero extends UntypedActor {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Object arg0) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Received = " + arg0);
  }

}
```

I start the Hero using the below code

```
import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import akka.actor.ActorSystem;
import akka.actor.Props;

public class TestHero {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("testHero");
    ActorRef master = system.actorOf(Props.create(Hero.class), "master");
    master.tell("I am here", ActorRef.noSender());
}

}
```

When I run the above code I get the message "Received = I am Here".

Now I have my Messenger class's constructor as follows

```
private static ActorRef hero;

public Messenger() {
    ActorSelection master = context().actorSelection("akka://localhost/user/serviceA/master");
    hero = master.anchor();
}
```

When I print the hero object it is always null. What am I missing here? Is this the right way to search for an Actor. The point is these 2 actors will be running in 2 different JVMs.

I enabled remoting and modified the Messenger class as below.

```
import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import akka.actor.ActorSelection;
import akka.actor.ActorSystem;
import akka.actor.Props;
import akka.actor.UntypedActor;

public class Messenger extends UntypedActor {

private static ActorRef hero;

public Messenger() {
    ActorSelection master = context().actorSelection("akka.tcp://testHero@127.0.0.1:2552/user/master");
    System.out.println(master);
    hero = master.anchor();

}

@Override
public void onReceive(Object arg0) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("msg = " + arg0);
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("test");
    ActorRef actor = system.actorOf(Props.create(Messenger.class), "msgnr");
    System.out.println(actor.getClass() + " >> " + actor);
    System.out.println(hero);
    actor.tell("Hi", hero);
}

}
```

The output is given below

class akka.actor.RepointableActorRef >> Actor[akka://test/user/msgnr#-975452280]
null
ActorSelection[Anchor(akka://test/deadLetters), Path(/user/master)]
msg = Hi

How to wait till the Messenger is created so that hero actor ref is instantiated?

Comment: You should read up on the Remoting documentation on the Akka site.  If you truly want to look up an actor in a different JVM then you will need remoting enabled and you will need to give the correct remote capable path:  http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.11/java/remoting.html

Comment: `ActorSelection.anchor` isn't part of the public API.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by adding an application.conf file to the Messenger also.